# Saving / Loading Images from android gallery as bitmap?

Tags: java, android, image

I am a beginner Android developer and I need to know how to Save and Load images (Bitmaps) from the Android Gallery, But I dont even know where to start! Can someone help me to know where to get started, or even look?

Answer (score 1):

Cody, check out android's imageView. Also, here is a list of some pretty useful android tutorials for beginners.

http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/basic-android-tutorials-t11401.html

-Evan